# Hi, How do i make the end result of this randomly generated local variable into a global variable? Python

Tags: python, global-variables, global

So this is what i got:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']

y = ['a', 'b', 'c']


def stuff(this, that):
  this = x[randint(0, 2)]
  that = y[randint(0, 2)]
  while this != 'c' or that != 'c'
     print "some %r stuff here etc..." % (this, that)
     this = x[randint(0, 2)]
     that = y[randint(0, 2)] 

stuff(x[randint(0, 2)], x[randint(0, 2)])
```

**this is just a "gist" of the program of course.**

So everything works fine like i want it to untill after this part.
the problem i have is when i try to print out or use the end result of the successful
while-loop globally, i obviously get a NameError, and when i try to add global to the variable inside the function, i get SyntaxError: name 'blah' is global and local.
If i create the random variable outside the function then what i print out is THAT variable, and not the one that satisfied the while-loop statement.

Now i know i can just put the print in the function, but this is only a piece of a larger
program that repeats the basic steps above. I want to print the total result out together
as so:

```
print "blah blah is %r, and %r %r %r etc.. blah blah.." % (x, y, z, a, b, etc)
```

How do remedy this so i can accurately gather the variables that satisfy the while-loop and use them in other parts of the whole program?
PS: Sorry for the mess, Im still in the learners phase..

Comment: Use `random.choice(x)` instead of `x[random.randint(0,2)]`.

Comment: Just declare them `global` at the top of the function.

Comment: RTFM! `global` variables will be your friends.

Comment: @Mic: Right up until they stab you in the back. Seriously, global variables are generally *not* the way you want to structure your program.

Comment: agreed, but looks like the op is in the process of learning, so as a beginner it's one way to get started. But yes, for anything else than testing code, do not use global variables as in any language.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `return` statement to return the result to the caller. This is the preferred way to pass variables around (`global` is not ideal since it clutters the global namespace and can create name clash problems later on).

```
def pick_random(x, y):
    return random.choice(x), random.choice(y)

this, that = pick_random(x, y)
```

If you want to keep producing values from a function, you can use *`yield`*:

```
def pick_random(x, y):
    while True:
        this, that = random.choice(x), random.choice(y)
        if this == 'c' and that == 'c':
            return
        yield this, that

for this, that in pick_random(x, y):
    print this, that
```